# Formatting the output of Sys.time() with timezone in R using format.Posix*

Tags: r, date, formatting, timezone, format

I am trying to figure out how to format the output of `Sys.time()` in R.

For example:

```
t <- Sys.time()
print(t)
# [1] "2017-07-26 09:41:29 CEST"
```

which is correct.

I want to make a string out of `t` made of the date, the hour and minute and the timezone. 
I can use

```
format(t, format = "%F %R %Z")
# [1] "2017-07-26 09:41 CEST"
```

Which is what I expect.

However, I am having a hard time understanding the output if I set the timezone explicitly. For example:

```
format(t, format = "%F %R %Z", tz = "Europe/Stockholm")
# [1] "2017-07-26 09:41 CEST"
```

produces what I expect, but:

```
format(t, format = "%F %R %Z", tz = "CEST")
# [1] "2017-07-26 07:41 CEST"
```

which I think is wrong, I would have expected the output to be `"2017-07-26 09:41 CEST"` or `"2017-07-26 09:41 Europe/Stockholm"`

Also

```
format(t, format = "%F %R %Z", tz = "UTC+02:00")
# [1] "2017-07-26 05:41 UTC"
```

which I find even weirder, since I would have expected the output to be `"2017-07-26 10:41 UTC+02:00"`

In the answer I would like to know two things:

- why my examples give the output they give?
- is there any way to have the timezone always written like `"2017-07-26 10:41 UTC+02:00"` or `"2017-07-26 10:41 Europe/Stockholm"`?

Comment: You assume you can use "random" input to the timezone argument.  You can't.  Stick with the 'named' timezone (such as 'Europe/Stockholm').   An unidentified / unknown argument leads to a (silent) UTC setting.

Comment: But why does `format(Sys.time(), format = "%F %R %Z", tz = "I have no clue")` return `"2017-07-26 15:50 "`  instead of `"2017-07-26 15:50 CEST"`?

Comment: Thanks, but I am still a bit confused by the inconsistent behavior of sometimes including the timezone in the output, and sometimes leaving it out. For example, `format(Sys.time(), format = "%F %R %Z", tz = "aaaaaa b")` returns `"2017-07-26 15:55 aaaaaa"`, although it is equally garbage as 'I have no clue'. Not that I am planning on messing with timezones.

Comment: Strange, it's exactly what I type in my console.. Well I'll stop wasting your time on my non-issue version of this question. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though R displays time zone in the console as `"CEST"` (which is `%Z`), there is no valid timezone by that name. You can check `OlsonNames()` for valid timezone names.

```
any(grepl("CEST", OlsonNames()))
#[1] FALSE
```

For cases when the timezone is displayed as `CEST`, it is still stored as `"Europe/Stockholm"` internally. We can check using `dput`

```
as.POSIXct("2017-07-26 10:46:12", tz = "Europe/Stockholm")
#[1] "2017-07-26 10:46:12 CEST"

dput(as.POSIXct("2017-07-26 10:46:12", tz = "Europe/Stockholm"))
#structure(1501058772, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Europe/Stockholm")
```

Note that `%Z` is only for output and is not reliable for input. `CEST` is not a valid value for `tz` and if you use invalid values for `tz`, they will commonly be treated as `UTC` (Read more at `?format.POSIXct` or `?strptime`). That is why you get unexpected output with `format(t, format = "%F %R %Z", tz = "CEST")`

Just use `"Europe/Stockholm"` explicitly.

```
any(grepl("Europe/Stockholm", OlsonNames()))
#[1] TRUE
```

As for formatting time in the specific format, try

```
format(as.POSIXct("2017-07-26 10:46:12", tz = "UTC"), "%F %R UTC%z")
#[1] "2017-07-26 10:46 UTC+0000"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I do have some doubt though: why when using explicitely "UTC+02:00" it does'n default to UTC (since it's not in OlsonNames()) but actually removes two hours? also, is there a way to have the timezone formatted in other "OlsonNames" valid format?

Comment: Another use case I have is that often I am given timestamps (as number of seconds from 1970-01-01 in UTC) and the timezone in formats like "GMT+01:00". In some cases there are also time zones like "GMT+08:30" and I need to handle such cases to get the local time, how can I do that in R